# How to copy all the data from one redshift cluster to another redshift cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I want to copy all the data from one redshift cluster to another new redshift cluster within the same account while making sure all the schemas ,users, groups etc are restored.
What to know what is the best way to achieve this.
1)Manual snapshot
2)Unloading the data to s3 and copying the data to the new cluster.

If have to use the second option I want to know how this can be done.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to take a snapshot and restore it to a new cluster manually. However, If you modify the data in the original cluster after taking the snapshot, the new cluster will not retain the modified data, so I recommend you thoroughly consider your migration plan.